# Update multiple selectInput using actionButton, only the last one can work well

Tags: r, shiny

I try to use `actionButton()` to update the choices of multiple `selectInput()`, after second click, the choices did updated but only the last `selectInput()` updated in that `observeEvent()` can work well, the others can't be chosen.

I can't see any conflict in my code, what exactly caused this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
      selectInput("select1", "Select 1", choices = c(Choose = "", "1", "11", "111")),
      selectInput("select2", "Select 2", choices = c(Choose = "", "1", "22", "222")),
      selectInput("select3", "Select 3", choices = c(Choose = "", "3", "33", "333")),
      actionButton("btn123", "update1, update2 and update3, second click, only 3 work")
    ),
    column(width = 4,
      selectInput("selectA", "Select A", choices = c(Choose = "", "A", "AA", "AAA")),
      selectInput("selectB", "Select B", choices = c(Choose = "", "B", "BB", "BBB")),
      selectInput("selectC", "Select C", choices = c(Choose = "", "C", "CC", "CCC")),
      actionButton("btnABC", "updateC, updateB and updateA, second click, only A work")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c(1:3),
    col2 = c(4:6),
    col3 = c(7:9)
  )
  rownames(df) = c("row1", "row2", "row3")

  observeEvent(input$btn123, {
    if (input$btn123 %% 2 == 0) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "select1", choices = c(Choose = "", rownames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "select2", choices = c(Choose = "", rownames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "select3", choices = c(Choose = "", rownames(df)))
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "select1", choices = c(Choose = "", colnames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "select2", choices = c(Choose = "", colnames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "select3", choices = c(Choose = "", colnames(df)))
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$btnABC, {
    if (input$btnABC %% 2 == 0) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectC", choices = c(Choose = "", rownames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectB", choices = c(Choose = "", rownames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectA", choices = c(Choose = "", rownames(df)))
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectC", choices = c(Choose = "", colnames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectB", choices = c(Choose = "", colnames(df)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectA", choices = c(Choose = "", colnames(df)))
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: All of them work fine.  I don't see any issues.  Perhaps you need to re-start your R and/or RStudio sessions.

Comment: Thank you for testing, I try to update the shiny using `install_github()`, it solved